# android:autofilledHighlight not working correctly on left aligned Entry

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

In my project i have some entry boxes with text align central and text align left, i also have the android property android:autofilledHighlight set to transparent as i don't want to see the highlight

on the centred text the transparent highlight works perfectly but on left align it doesn't at all, this is what the page is setup to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="xxxxx.DebugPage">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Entry x:Name="Email" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
            <Entry x:Name="ConfirmEmail" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

this is the part of styles.xml:

```
<style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
<!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette -->
<!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
<item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
<!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
<!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
     which is used to tint widgets -->
<item name="colorAccent">#006666</item>
<!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
     colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

<item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>

<item name="android:autofilledHighlight">@color/colorTransparent</item>
</style>
```

when actually using the autofill option this is what i'm presented with:

[image: issue]

Is there something i'm missing or is this a bug within Android/Xamarin?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use custom renderer to set the `importantForAutofill` property to `no`.

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(MyEntryRenderer))]
namespace Your namespace
{
  class MyEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
  {
    public MyEntryRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            
           Control.ImportantForAutofill = ImportantForAutofill.No;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**Update**,try to block autofill for an entire activity.

Add below codes in your MainActivity:

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
       ...           
       Window.DecorView.ImportantForAutofill = ImportantForAutofill.NoExcludeDescendants;
    }
```

Comment: That looked promising but doesn't seem to change anything that I can tell, i tried "No" and "NoExcludeDescendants" and the problem is still persisting

Comment: @DanScott You could try to block autofill for an entire activity, try the method above.

Comment: Same issue, I tried adding it in various parts of the OnCreate function as I have other stuff in there but the issue still remains

thanks for your help so far by the way

Comment: @DanScott It's weird.These are two common ways to cancel the autofill background, and you might want to try testing them on other devices.